# The type or namespace name 'nametest' could not be found

Tags: c#

error : The type or namespace name 'ihub' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can't useing class, but I've created a class(Is class scaffold db).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odui7.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fe2g.png)

I use .net6

I need using class scaffold db in api proj.

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Please spend some time i9n the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question. Pictures of code are not acceptable unless they actually add value but, even then, you need to provide the code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: I imagine that English is not your native language but you also need to try a bit harder to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. You say that you can't use a class but you tried using a class. That doesn't make much sense. If your English is not good, that generally means that more words is better than less, so we can piece the real issue together from all the parts.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I say "  I can not using class , but I've created a class " not  "using a class" , sorry english is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is Case-sensitive. Be sure have a look at this. Your scaffold class resides in Namespace `Ihub.Mobile.data.Models.Context` but you wrote  `using ihub.data.Models.Context` (lowercase "i" and left out the word "Mobile").